# TinyMce Formatting is not supported by prawns

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, tinymce, prawn

[image][image]

I am using TinyMce Rich Text Editor in my rails application and trying to generate pdf using prawns then text formatting is not supported by prawns.

Suppose I created description using text editor as ***

***- This is simple description***

---

When I am trying to show this description in pdf using prawn then it shows as simple text like -

This is simple description.

Is there any way to show description as formatted.

```
           @pdf=pdf
           pdf.text "Test"

            pdf.move_down(30)
            rr = Model.find(106)
            items = [[rr.name,strip_tags(rr.definition)]]


             pdf.table(items) do |table|
                 table.rows(1..3).width = 72
             end
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you want? What you tried? Explain problem, please

Comment: suppose I am created description using tinymce rich text editor.In the description I have selected some word italic and change  font color of some words red and some words yellow. when I am trying to show this description in PDF using prawn then it shows simple as plain text .My issue is to show the description as formatted using text editor.

Comment: > items = [[rr.name,strip_tags(rr.definition)]] < ----  what is this line doing

Comment: you are stripping tags??

Comment: if i am not using strip_tag then it shows  html syntax with data.